# How many triangles are possible with no side greater than $4$ units?

Tags: combinatorics, triangles

> Consider a triangle having integer sides such that so side is greater than $4$ units.How many such triangles are possible?

I could not solve it by trying to use combinatorics.

So, how to do it?

Thanks fro any help.

The original question came from here: http://www.examrace.com/d/pdf/efaf18b/NSEJS-Solved-Paper-2012.pdf

Comment: I don't think there are any. The lowest Pythagorean triple is (3,4,5).

Comment: @BenLongo-I am sorry but I don't agree with you....

Comment: @BenLongo-Where is it mentioned right angled triangle?

Comment: You are correct, I misread the question.

Comment: Are reflections counted as different triangles?

Comment: @IanMiller-reflections?what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Is (4,3,2) different to (4,2,3)?

Comment: @IanMiller-Yes....If $AB=4,BC=3,CA=2$ it is different from $AB=4,BC=2,CA=3...$

Comment: How about $(3,3,1)$ and $(3,1,3)$  Are they different?

Comment: @RossMillikan-yesh they are different....although they can be super imposed on one another....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions in the PDF linked are incorrect. They have calculated $4\times3\times2$ which is only counting scalene triangles including rotations and reflections and then it excludes 7 without even listing them all. I would strong recommend you get official solutions from the Indian Association of Physics Teachers rather than from 3rd party sites.

**My solution:**

Scalene triangles: $\space^4C_3=4$, however $(1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,3,4)$ are not allowed.

Isoceles trianges: $\space^4P_2=12$, however $(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,1,4),(2,2,4)$ are not allowed. So $8$ more.

Equilateral: $\space^4C_1$, so $4$ more.

Total: $1+8+4=13$ triangles.

List: $(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 3), (1, 4, 4), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2,
   3, 3), (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 4), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 4), (3, 4, 4), (4, 
  4, 4)$

Comment: Some calculation error has crept in....$6+8+4=18$ not $17$..

Comment: Yeh some counting errors too. I get 14 now.

Comment: No,i suppose you have missed out something....its gonna be $17$...

Comment: Based on your comment to @Ross Millikan above each rotation is distinct. If that's the case you have a lot more than 17 triangles. Can you clarify (in your original question) about rotation and reflection please.

Comment: Would you mind if I sent you the link where I found the question?

Comment: The more information you can supply to others the better answer you will get. Please add it to your original question so it is easily visible to others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31936/discussion-between-tatan-and-ian-miller).

Answer (score 1):

With numbers this small, just list them by hand.  Let the sides be $a,b,c$ with $a \le b \le c$  How many are there with $c=1?$  With $c=2?$ Etc.  If the limit were higher, I would solve it by hand for small $c$, then look for a general expression.  It should not be more than quadratic in $c$.  Then summing over $c$ will be no more than cubic.

Comment: I know the answer is $17$ by simple counting....but what is a more mathematical way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

More generally, the number of integer triangles with a greatest side length of $c$ is given by

$$n=\left\lceil \frac{c+1}{2}\right\rceil \cdot \left\lfloor\frac{c+1}{2} \right\rfloor $$

#### Proof

Let $(i, j ,k)$ be a sequence of non negative integers that gives the lengths of the sides of a triangle. We restrict our attention to incongruent triangles and therefore triples where $i\le j\le k$ and $k\le i + j$. The associated triangle has perimeter, $p=i+j+k$.

Let $A$ denote the set of *all* triangular triples, Let $B$ denote the set of all *non-degenerate* triples. For both of these sets $\mathscr A$, let $\mathscr A(p)$ denote the subset of triples in $\mathscr A$ with sum equal to $p$.

For each non-negative integer $k$, let $L_\alpha(k)$ denote the number of triangular triples of each type with longest side $k$.

In non-degenerate triples $2k<(i+j)+k=p\le k+k+k=3k$. Thus for a fixed value of $k$, $2k+1\le p \le 3k$; and for a fixed value of $p$, $p/3\le k \le (p-1)/2$. Because $k$ is an integer

$$\lceil p/3\rceil\le k \le \lfloor (p-1)/2 \rfloor$$

Let $f(p, k)$ denote the number of triangular triples (degenerate or not) with perimeter $p$ and largest entry $k$. Clearly the largest value for $j$ is $k$ in which case $i$ takes its smallest possible value, $p-2k$. Since $2i\le i+j=p-k$, $i\le(p-k)/2$; so the largest possible value of $i$ is $\lfloor (p-k)/2\rfloor$. Hence

$$f(p, k)=\lfloor (p-k)/2 \rfloor -(p-2k) + 1 = \lfloor (p-k)/2-(p-2k)+1\rfloor$$
$$=\lfloor (3k-p+2)/2 \rfloor$$

Then

$$L_b(k)=\sum_{p=2k+1}^{3k}\lfloor(3k-p+2)/2 \rfloor=\sum_{m=2}^{k+1}\lfloor  m/2 \rfloor$$

If $k=2q$, $L_b(k)=2\{1+2+\cdots+q\}=q(q+1)$. If $k=2q+1$, $L_b(k)=q(q+1)+(q+1)$. Thus for all $k$
$$L_b(k)=\lfloor(k+1)/2\rfloor\cdot \lceil(k+1)/2 \rceil$$

Comment: So,here greatest length=$4$,So,the product =$2*2=4$ which is surely not the answer....

Comment: @tatan, it's actually $3\cdot 2$, which is what I got when the longest side is 4. Note that the first thing is the ceiling.

Comment: @Ben Longo, could you discuss how you got that?

Comment: @dmk-$c=4$....so,$\frac {c+1}{2}=2.5$....Box of $2.5$ is $2$.It's the same in both cases....